# Query inside query fails with node native driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I got this code in the mongo client that produces what I expect:

```
db.bookings.find().forEach(
    function(booking) {
        booking.visitor = db.visitor.findOne({id:booking.visitor_id});
        db.bookingsReloaded.insert(booking)
    }
)
```

The code in node 10.x and mongo native driver (v2.1.x) looks like this:

```
bookings.find({}).each(
function(err, booking){
    if (booking == null ){
        ...
    } else {
        booking.visitor = booking.findOne({id:booking.visitor_id});
        bookingsReloaded.insert(booking);           
    }
});
```

While after execution of the code (bookings and visitor are existing collections) the new collection bookingsReloaded contains the expected results (the visitor doc embedded) when executed with the mongo client, the node code doesn't work, it looks like it doesn't even execute the findOne statement.

Probably something trivial that I should have known, but I don't :(

Answer (score 0):

The mongo client shell is synchronous, while node.js is asynchronous. So the result of a `findOne` call is delivered via a callback rather than returned.

So your node.js code would need to look like this instead:

```
bookings.find({}).each(
    function(err, booking){
        if (booking == null ){
            ...
        } else {
            visitors.findOne({id: booking.visitor_id}, function(err, visitor) {
                booking.visitor = visitor;
                bookingsReloaded.insert(booking, function (err, inserted) {
                    ...error handling...
                });           
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Johnny - thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, that doesn't solve the issue. I have changed the code so that the insert is inside the findOne call. However, the result is that the code of the function called in the findOne doesn't get executed ...

Comment: @RalphMueller It's best to add comments to clarify instead of editing answers. Anyway, thanks for clarifying it's the `visitors` collection that queried with `findOne`.  Should the `findOne` be querying against the `_id` fields instead of `id`?

Comment: oops, sorry, I'm a newbee. Anyway - I translated the collection names from German for better understanding.  So it is really visitors.findOne with an Id for the visitor stored in the bookings collection. The same visitors.findOne query works if I just put it in the beginning of my little test app, but not inside the code as shown in the example (now with the insert command in the function called by the findOne